# How do I create a link on form submission in another page and get the contents of the text submitted on the linked page?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been recently trying to create a query (Ask a question) page in HTML. I have a form that uses the get method and I know that is one way to send data across pages and use it with JavaScript. Is it possible to create a link with the form's data inside the linked page?

```js
// Get the contents of  //
   
var inputBox = document.getElementById('QueryTitle');
// Use the onkeyup to get the values of user input // 
 
inputBox.onkeyup = function(){

// MAKE NO BAD TAGS APPEAR IN QUESTIONS //
const goodTags = ['<b>' , '</b>' , '<i>' , '</i>' , '<br>' , '</br>']
var tag = inputBox.value.match(/<.+>/)
if (tag && !goodTags.includes(tag[0])) { inputBox.value = inputBox.value.replace(tag[0], '') };

  document.getElementById('QueryTitleOutput').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
 }
 // Get the questions contents, normally in the textarea of the page //
   
  var textarea = document.getElementById('QueryInput');
  
// Use the onkeyup to get the values of user input //
textarea.onkeyup = function(){

// MAKE NO BAD TAGS APPEAR IN QUESTIONS //
const goodTags = ['<b>' , '</b>' , '<i>' , '</i>' , '<br>' , '</br>']
var tag = textarea.value.match(/<.+>/)
if (tag && !goodTags.includes(tag[0])) { textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(tag[0], '') };

    document.getElementById('QueryOutputFrame').innerHTML = textarea.value;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This the form that uses the get method to show data in the URL -->
<form action="Get Text As A Link.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="QueryTitle" name="QueryTitle" placeholder="Ask Something">
   <br>
     <br>
 <!-- this is the main query textarea !-->
  <textarea id="QueryInput" name="QueryInput" style="width: 780px; height: 200px;">
   </textarea>
  <!-- Widgets for the textarea !-->
 <br>
   <div id="QueryTitleOutput">
    </div>
      <br> 
     <br>   
   <div id="QueryOutputFrame" style="width: 90%; height: 10em;">
   </div>
  </center>
   <br>
    <br>
     <br>
      <br>
     <br>
    <center>
   <input type="submit" id="final" value="Submit Question" class="unhidden" class="btn btn-submit"  onclick="location.href = 'Get Text As A Link.html';" onSubmit="">
  </center>
 </form>
```

Comment: So you want to construct a URL with the data that has been entered in your form?

Comment: Yes. I just want to create a simple query page for users who might need it. All I know is that if I use the get method I can gather the data in the URL.

Comment: You can do the same with the POST method. Is there a specific reason for using get? Also you keep mentioning queries. Do you need a SQL query to be generated so you can fetch information?

Having your current code as a working example could help solving this issue quicker.

Comment: Well, it just found it easier that way. It makes it easier for me only because I can see the data entered in the URL. That way I'll see what is and isn't entered. I'll edit my quesiton and provide the code

Comment: The reason why I keep mentioning queries is because most website with forums or just have a community have this. I just don't understand how they do it.. Also, to the SQL question; not really. I want to limit my risk of SQL Injection.